# im getting blank space at left side and bottom of site

Tags: html, css, space

im getting this blank space, i searched for similar questions and applied a number of solutions but none of them worked, i discover if i erase the containerCont div the problem dissapears, thanks

I have already posted this question, with an url to the page itself, somebody told i should post a scan, but stack overflow requires at least 10 reputation to post images, so i dont know how to illustrate my problem so here is the url again: http://www.finestra.mx/informe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given `margin-top` and also `top` for footer. Removing `top:3px;` solves the problem.

```
#downText {
    width: 272px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 3px;

    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks men, that removed the bottom space, what about the right side space?